# How to add vaadin instead of thymeleaf in existing project in intellij?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, thymeleaf, vaadin

I have few projects with vaadin created by spring.io and everything works. Now I want to add vaadin to existing project, where I used thymeleaf. When I added vaadin maven dependencies and deleted thymeleaf dependency my classes see vaadin bibliotecs but it not compile. Intellij says that not found resources. I need to add sth more than dependiencies?

It looks like vaadin doesn't start at all, the application compilation takes 5 seconds, where in other applications with vaadin the application starts after more than 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to go to https://vaadin.com/start/latest and create a new project.

And then copy the old code to the new project.